# Post a multipart/form-data using C++ with winhttp to flask

Tags: python, c++, rest, flask, winhttp

I used the following code to send `formData` to my Flask server, and I tried to read `formData` using `request.files` but the result is `immutablemultidict([])`.

What should I do to get data as `formData`?

I can get `request.get_data` or `request.data`.

```
DWORD dwSize = 0;
LPVOID lpOutBuffer = NULL;

std::wstring filePath = L"C:img.png";

std::vector<char> fileContent = ReadFileContent(filePath);

HINTERNET hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

if (!hSession) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpOpen failed!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"127.0.0.0", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

if (!hConnect) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpConnect failed!" << std::endl;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 1;
}

std::wstring boundary = L"--------------------------" + std::to_wstring(GetTickCount64());;

std::wstring headers = L"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

std::wstring formData = L"--" + boundary + L"\r\n"
    L"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filePath + L"\"\r\n"
    L"Content-Type: image/*\r\n\r\n";
std::wstring finalBoundary = L"\r\n--" + boundary + L"--\r\n";


hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST",
    L"/upload", 
    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
    0);

if (!hRequest) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpOpenRequest failed!" << std::endl;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 1;
}

DWORD dwOption = WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY_NEVER;
WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY, &dwOption, sizeof(dwOption));

BOOL bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, headers.c_str(),
    headers.length(), 0, 0, fileContent.size() + formData.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) +
    finalBoundary.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), 0);

if (!bResults) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpSendRequest failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 1;
}

bResults = WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, formData.data(), formData.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), 0);
bResults = WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, fileContent.data(), fileContent.size(), 0);
bResults = WinHttpWriteData(hRequest, finalBoundary.data(), finalBoundary.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), 0);

if (!bResults) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpWriteData failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 1;
}

bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

if (!bResults) {
    std::wcerr << L"WinHttpReceiveResponse failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 1;
}
```

I want to see `ImmutableMultiDict(['file'], <filename: 'img.png' ('image/png')>)]` in the Python terminal. Here are my results:
[image]

Comment: Why does `filename` has whole path (in the result image)?

Comment: You seem to be sending UTF-16 bytes (the internal encoding used by `std::wstring`) to the web server, but you never informed the header of that fact. Moreover, the MIME boundaries are supposed to show up exactly as they are in the headers. To clear up any confusion you should capture the HTTP request as sent and examine its bytes in a hex editor. If you see repeating patterns of the form `00 xx 00 yy 00 zz` (with xx yy zz random) you are sending UTF-16 and your headers should accomodate that.